# NUKE keyframes animation curve

Tags: animation, bezier, keyframe, nuke

I'm parsing the NUKE software keyframe animation format. It's description is here: https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/developers/70/ndkdevguide/advanced/curveformat.html

It uses these numbers to define the curve. ("x" x-value) y-value ("s" l-slope) ("t" r-slope) ("u" l-angle) ("v" r-angle)

x,y,slope are fine, but I'm confused by the "angle". I'm assuming l and r refer to left and right side of the anchor point. The l-angle and r-angle seem more like a function of the length of the handle to me. It also seems like the maximum value is 3

Below are some examples with image (note, the grid in the images doesn't show units "correctly", but the slope values mean what you'd think they mean, they say how much increase in y per x value)

x40 399.5495605 s21.10000038 u3 v0.9411216378

[image: image description]

Here's another example, note l-angle is still 3 (the maximum, but I had to decrease the slope)

x40 399.5495605 s5.900000095 u3 v0.9411216378

[image: description]

Another one:

x40 399.5495605 s6 u0.2508043051 v0.9411216378

[image: description]

And an example where l-slope and r-slope is different, neither u,v are provided, so per docs default to 1 (whatever that means)

x1 355 x40 399.5495605 s6 t-6.953211784

[image]

Anyone have ideas about what the "angle" values mean in this context? I'm trying to convert this format into the more normal bezier curve definition.

(I also posted this question in a NUKE forum: https://community.foundry.com/discuss/topic/160372/curve-serialisation-format)

EDIT: (about the grids not showing "correct units")
[image]

Comment: it looks like you're not mentioning which interpolation and extrapolation these curves use? But also, if the documentation is insufficient, you should _definitely_ also contact Nuke and ask report that problem to them, and request a docs update so that the entire Nuke-using world can benefit from docs improvements.

Comment: having said that, this part of the docs matters: "If an l-slope is set and no r-slope then the lslope should be used for both." So in the curves you're showing, that tangent line segment should be the same length on both sides, as none of them list an explicit r-slope, rather than the image you're showing, where one side is notably longer than the other.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The slopes don't seem to affect length (the u/v or angle values do that, not sure why they're called angle), I've provided another example with two different s/t values (l-slope and r-slope), but with no u/v, meaning those default to 1

Comment: Can't say that last curve makes any sense given those values (also, don't mark it as an "edit", just keep the post a single post, it's only been a few hours, not months or years, and the edit's just "more of the same" details, not completely new information because the underlying tech stack changed =) so I'd strongly encourage you to actually contact the Nuke folks as well (and tell them about this post). And then if they give you an answer, you can write up the solution as answer for future visitors.

Comment: Sure, I've posted it in a nuke forum, but the slopes make sense, the grid doesn't show actual/correct values though, so that might be why slope doesn't look correct in the images, but slope makes sense, it's just the u/v (l-angle/r-angle) I don't understand

Comment: Good idea to link to that forum post in your question, too. Also if the grid doesn't line up with the units, please correct that. Your images are here to help people understand the problem, not keep it confusing =)

Comment: I am confused by
`the grid in the images doesn't show units "correctly"`
What _does_ it show then?

Comment: I've updated the post at the end to show what I mean, the grid always just looks square on the screen, instead of reflecting how the x/y axis is scaled (the point is that the slope values are what the name implies)